# Почему при передаче модели из контроллера в представление возникает ошибка NullReferenceException в ASP .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, null

Хочу передать несколько моделей в представление из контроллера и использую для этого отдельный класс, который используется для хранения нескольких моделей. Он называется AllClasses:

```
public class AllClasses
{
    public List<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
    public List<Basket> Baskets { get; set; }
    public List<Executor> Executors { get; set; }
    public List<Feedback> Feedbacks { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public List<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<UserData> UserDatas { get; set; }
}
```

Решил в своём контроллере создать объект данного класса и записать туда несколько моделей:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ServiceList()
{
    var allClasses = new AllClasses()
    {
        Executors = db.Executors.ToList(),
        Services = db.Services.ToList(),
        Users = db.Users.ToList()
    };

    return View(allClasses);
}
```

Во View пытаюсь создать объект Services, в который передаю полученный из контроллера объект класса:

```
@page
@model WebSite.Models.AllClasses
@{
    Layout = null;
    Service service1 = Model.Services[0];
}
```

И тут выдаётся ошибка `System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`. Подскажите, как это исправить? Вроде в контроллере все объекты заполняю, поэтому они не должны быть пустыми.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы перепутали View и Razor Pages. Если вы используете обычный MVC, то деректива `@page` вам не нужна, т.к. с ней смысл `@model` меняется. В MVC она указывает на то, что у вашей View есть некая модель (данные которые вы будете отображать например), тогда как в Razor Pages это указывает на PageModel, но т.к. у вас указана не правильная PageModel, приложение разваливается.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало! Объясните тогда мне такой момент - в каких случаях можно использовать PageModel? Чтобы определять какие-то внутренние переменные или модели в Razor Pages чтобы не обращаться к ним через "@"?

Comment: MVC View и Razor Pages, это разные способы написания приложения, для Razor Pages вам не нужен контроллер вообще, а вся логика и данные находятся непосредственно на странице или в PageModel (чем-то это может быть похоже на code-behind из WinForms/WPF), в основном предназначено для простых страниц